# Change Password notification text on mail

Tags: email, password

I am want to re-ride core function `wp_update_user()`

In this function there is text `This notice confirms that your password was changed on ###SITENAME###.` that i want replace with some other word.

I have tried to re-ride as

```
function wp_update_user($userdata) {
    if ( $userdata instanceof stdClass ) {
        $userdata = get_object_vars( $userdata );
    } elseif ( $userdata instanceof WP_User ) {
        $userdata = $userdata->to_array();
    }

    $ID = isset( $userdata['ID'] ) ? (int) $userdata['ID'] : 0;
    if ( ! $ID ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_user_id', __( 'Invalid user ID.' ) );
    }

    // First, get all of the original fields
    $user_obj = get_userdata( $ID );
    if ( ! $user_obj ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_user_id', __( 'Invalid user ID.' ) );
    }

    $user = $user_obj->to_array();

    // Add additional custom fields
    foreach ( _get_additional_user_keys( $user_obj ) as $key ) {
        $user[ $key ] = get_user_meta( $ID, $key, true );
    }

    // Escape data pulled from DB.
    $user = add_magic_quotes( $user );

    if ( ! empty($userdata['user_pass']) ) {
        // If password is changing, hash it now
        $plaintext_pass = $userdata['user_pass'];
        $userdata['user_pass'] = wp_hash_password( $userdata['user_pass'] );

        /**
         * Filter whether to send the password change email.
         *
         * @since 4.3.0
         *
         * @see wp_insert_user() For `$user` and `$userdata` fields.
         *
         * @param bool  $send     Whether to send the email.
         * @param array $user     The original user array.
         * @param array $userdata The updated user array.
         *
         */
        $send_password_change_email = apply_filters( 'send_password_change_email', true, $user, $userdata );
    }

    if ( isset( $userdata['user_email'] ) && $user['user_email'] !== $userdata['user_email'] ) {
        /**
         * Filter whether to send the email change email.
         *
         * @since 4.3.0
         *
         * @see wp_insert_user() For `$user` and `$userdata` fields.
         *
         * @param bool  $send     Whether to send the email.
         * @param array $user     The original user array.
         * @param array $userdata The updated user array.
         *
         */
        $send_email_change_email = apply_filters( 'send_email_change_email', true, $user, $userdata );
    }

    wp_cache_delete( $user['user_email'], 'useremail' );

    // Merge old and new fields with new fields overwriting old ones.
    $userdata = array_merge( $user, $userdata );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {

        $blog_name = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ) );

        if ( ! empty( $send_password_change_email ) ) {

            /* translators: Do not translate USERNAME, ADMIN_EMAIL, EMAIL, SITENAME, SITEURL: those are placeholders. */
            $pass_change_text = __( 'Hi ###USERNAME###,

This notice confirms that your password was changed on ###SITENAME###.

If you did not change your password, please contact the Site Administrator at
###ADMIN_EMAIL###

This email has been sent to ###EMAIL###

Regards,
All at ###SITENAME###
###SITEURL###' );

            $pass_change_email = array(
                'to'      => $user['user_email'],
                'subject' => __( '[%s] Notice of Password Change' ),
                'message' => $pass_change_text,
                'headers' => '',
            );

            /**
             * Filter the contents of the email sent when the user's password is changed.
             *
             * @since 4.3.0
             *
             * @param array $pass_change_email {
             *            Used to build wp_mail().
             *            @type string $to      The intended recipients. Add emails in a comma separated string.
             *            @type string $subject The subject of the email.
             *            @type string $message The content of the email.
             *                The following strings have a special meaning and will get replaced dynamically:
             *                - ###USERNAME###    The current user's username.
             *                - ###ADMIN_EMAIL### The admin email in case this was unexpected.
             *                - ###EMAIL###       The old email.
             *                - ###SITENAME###    The name of the site.
             *                - ###SITEURL###     The URL to the site.
             *            @type string $headers Headers. Add headers in a newline (\r\n) separated string.
             *        }
             * @param array $user     The original user array.
             * @param array $userdata The updated user array.
             *
             */
            $pass_change_email = apply_filters( 'password_change_email', $pass_change_email, $user, $userdata );

            $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###USERNAME###', $user['user_login'], $pass_change_email['message'] );
            $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###ADMIN_EMAIL###', get_option( 'admin_email' ), $pass_change_email['message'] );
            $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###EMAIL###', $user['user_email'], $pass_change_email['message'] );
            $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###SITENAME###', get_option( 'blogname' ), $pass_change_email['message'] );
            $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###SITEURL###', get_option( 'siteurl' ), $pass_change_email['message'] );

            wp_mail( $pass_change_email['to'], sprintf( $pass_change_email['subject'], $blog_name ), $pass_change_email['message'], $pass_change_email['headers'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $send_email_change_email ) ) {
            /* translators: Do not translate USERNAME, ADMIN_EMAIL, EMAIL, SITENAME, SITEURL: those are placeholders. */
            $email_change_text = __( 'Hi ###USERNAME###,

This notice confirms that your email was changed on ###SITENAME###.

If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at
###ADMIN_EMAIL###

This email has been sent to ###EMAIL###

Regards,
All at ###SITENAME###
###SITEURL###' );

            $email_change_email = array(
                'to'      => $user['user_email'],
                'subject' => __( '[%s] Notice of Email Change' ),
                'message' => $email_change_text,
                'headers' => '',
            );

            /**
             * Filter the contents of the email sent when the user's email is changed.
             *
             * @since 4.3.0
             *
             * @param array $email_change_email {
             *            Used to build wp_mail().
             *            @type string $to      The intended recipients.
             *            @type string $subject The subject of the email.
             *            @type string $message The content of the email.
             *                The following strings have a special meaning and will get replaced dynamically:
             *                - ###USERNAME###    The current user's username.
             *                - ###ADMIN_EMAIL### The admin email in case this was unexpected.
             *                - ###EMAIL###       The old email.
             *                - ###SITENAME###    The name of the site.
             *                - ###SITEURL###     The URL to the site.
             *            @type string $headers Headers.
             *        }
             * @param array $user The original user array.
             * @param array $userdata The updated user array.
             */
            $email_change_email = apply_filters( 'email_change_email', $email_change_email, $user, $userdata );

            $email_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###USERNAME###', $user['user_login'], $email_change_email['message'] );
            $email_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###ADMIN_EMAIL###', get_option( 'admin_email' ), $email_change_email['message'] );
            $email_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###EMAIL###', $user['user_email'], $email_change_email['message'] );
            $email_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###SITENAME###', get_option( 'blogname' ), $email_change_email['message'] );
            $email_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###SITEURL###', get_option( 'siteurl' ), $email_change_email['message'] );

            wp_mail( $email_change_email['to'], sprintf( $email_change_email['subject'], $blog_name ), $email_change_email['message'], $email_change_email['headers'] );
        }
    }

    // Update the cookies if the password changed.
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $current_user->ID == $ID ) {
        if ( isset($plaintext_pass) ) {
            wp_clear_auth_cookie();

            // Here we calculate the expiration length of the current auth cookie and compare it to the default expiration.
            // If it's greater than this, then we know the user checked 'Remember Me' when they logged in.
            $logged_in_cookie    = wp_parse_auth_cookie( '', 'logged_in' );
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php */
            $default_cookie_life = apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', ( 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ), $ID, false );
            $remember            = ( ( $logged_in_cookie['expiration'] - time() ) > $default_cookie_life );

            wp_set_auth_cookie( $ID, $remember );
        }
    }

    return $user_id;
}
```

and `add_filter('wp_update_user', 'wp_update_user', 1, 2);`

But show error like that you can not re-declare that function again.

So please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you only want to change the text of the mail. This you can do via the filter hook `password_change_email`. No need to redeclare the function, which you actually can't do. Below you find an example on how to use the `password_change_email` filter to change your message text.

```
add_filter( 
  'password_change_email', 
  'wpse207879_change_password_mail_message', 
  10, 
  3 
);
function wpse207879_change_password_mail_message( 
  $pass_change_mail, 
  $user, 
  $userdata 
) {
  $new_message_txt = __( 'Some text ###USERNAME### more text
    even more text ###EMAIL### more text after more text
    last bit of text ###SITENAME###' );
  $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;
  return $pass_change_mail;
}
```

I've tested this and it works. Just to clarify, this applies to the use case, in which one changes and updates the password via the backend user management.

Comment: Sorry but it still not working. after adding this is themes function files not showing any error but forget password and change password text is still same as default

Comment: Are you using WP 4.3+? @srapsware

Comment: Yes i am using 4.3.1 version.

Comment: Yes now i have tested on a new other WordPress site and found its working . i have installed a WP-profile manager plugin why which it was not working. its working without plugin . Any way thanks

Comment: @srapsware My pleasure!