# Change Password Confirmed Email Text

Tags: hooks, email, password

I've been struggling to find a hook I can use to edit the text in the password confirmed email that gets sent out when you've changed your password in WordPress.

Is there anyway to do this with a simple hook that I can add to the child themes functions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
add_filter( 'password_change_email', 'wpse207879_change_password_mail_message', 10, 3 );
function wpse207879_change_password_mail_message( $pass_change_mail, $user, $userdata ) {
  $new_message_txt = __( 'Some text ###USERNAME### more text
      even more text ###EMAIL### more text after more text
      last bit of text ###SITENAME###' );
  $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;
  return $pass_change_mail;
}
```

Reference of the above code is:
[Change Password notification text on mail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207879/change-password-notification-text-on-mail)

This filter is in the [`wp_update_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/) function and is [documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_change_email/).